# What is the name of the attack where a single node spin thousands of node and take control of the cluster?

Tags: blockchain

When we implement Raft for a decentralised public ledger a single node can easily take over the control of a full cluster by spinning thousands of nodes and making them to elect the malicious node as a leader. What is the name of this attack in security terms?

Comment: Are you referring to a [Sybil attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sybil_attack)?

Comment: I was not sure, thats why asked for the name describing the scenario. In sybil attack, a single node forge identities to appear as multiple node. But here a single node is spinning lot of nodes. Is it different or the same?